# Trigger method via JS class or via jQuery trigger()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cart

I have a `CartHandler` Javascript class that contains a method named `onAddToCart` for communication between the page and the cart API.

Part of the class is also a method named `updateCartDOM` for updating DOM content upon response from cart API.

```js
var CartHandler = function() {
  $(document.body)
    .on('click', 'form[name="addToCart"]', { CartHandler: this }, this.onAddToCart)
    .on('update_cart_dom', { CartHandler: this }, this.updateCartDOM);
};

CartHandler.prototype.onAddToCart = function(e) { /* ... */ };
CartHandler.prototype.updateCartDOM = function(e, cart) { /* ... */ };
```

There are two ways of triggering updating method:

1. Triggering a jQuery event: `$(document.body).trigger('update_cart_dom', [...]);`
2. Calling the update method directly since the class is the same: `e.data.CartHandler.updateCartDOM(...);`

What is the preferred way of triggering updating function? Does it make any difference regarding performance or security?

Comment: There's no right or wrong answer here. However, my preference is to always invoke a function directly; there's no need to use the DOM to call a function IMO.